# should the device name be narrow or wide for WM_DEVMODECHANGE?

Tags: c, winapi, unicode

I notice there is no `A`/`W` variations for `WM_DEVMODECHANGE`, yet it takes a string in the `LPARAM`.  I see no documentation (that I can find) that tells whether this string is narrow or wide.

Does anyone know what is appropriate for the `LPARAM`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your comments to Hans's answer, you are sending the message. This message is typically sent with `SendMessageTimeout`. Now, `SendMessageTimeout` has two versions, `SendMessageTimeoutW` and `SendMessageTimeoutA`. When you call `SendMessageTimeoutW`, you must supply Unicode text, and when you call `SendMessageTimeoutA` you supply ANSI text.

So, the discrimination of the type of data is not made by having two message identifiers, rather it is based on the function that is used to send the data.

Exactly the same applies when using `SendMessageW`/`SendMessageA`, `PostMessageW`/`PostMessageA`, and so on.

If you call `SendMessageTimeoutW`, using `HWND_BROADCAST` then you can expect that both ANSI and Unicode windows will receive your message. The messaging system ensures that the data that you sent is converted to the appropriate encoding for the window that receives the message.

Comment: Thanks.  I should have checked for the A/W on the SendMessageTimeout.  D'oh!  :)

Answer (score 3):

`WM_DEVMODECHANGE` is just a number, and there's only one of them.  Whether you get narrow or wide strings is determined by whether the window is Unicode or not.  Which is determined by how you created it, using either CreateWindowExA or CreateWindowExW().  And something you can find out later with IsWindowUnicode().

Comment: I'm sending this message, in this case.  So I will send a string in my window's registered format...

Comment: Erm, wait.  When you generate it yourself, you usually broadcast it and use SendMessageTimeout().